# Path Issue : ClearCase to TFS Migration

Tags: tfs, clearcase

I want to move some of the files from clearcase to TFS. Some of the code as actual path. AFter moving to TFS, Path unknown error happens. Because some of the folders get happend in TFS. how to solve this issue
can i map the base folder to a drive and work, is the a good way to work

Answer (score 2):

The ideal solution is to avoid full hard-coded path in your code, and only work with relative paths.

But in the meantime, you can put in place a workaround, using the command **[mklink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mklink)**, in order to establish a symlink between:

- the first part of a full path used in your ClearCase code
- the first path of the code as checked out in TFS

So if your code refers to:

```
C:\my\path\to\a\folder
```

But your code is checked out in:

```
C:\my\tfs\path\to\a\folder
```

You can make a symbolic link between `c:\path\path` and `c:\my\tfs\path`.